# complex string to double conversion

Tags: c#, casting, floating-point, double

I have strings in a XML file that ment to be doubles (or float) such as:

```
<VIPair>
<voltage>+100mV</voltage>
<current>+1.05pA</current>
</VIPair>

<VIPair>
<voltage>+5.00mV</voltage>
<current>+0.0035nA</current>
</VIPair>
```

The first pair will be "0.1" Volt and "0.00000000000105" Ampere.
The second pair would be "0.005" Volt and "0.000000000035" Ampere.

How can I convert them to double of float in C#?
Thanks.

P.S: I already can read them from xml file and at the moment I retrive them as string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this:

```
// Read string (if you do not want to use xml)
string test = "<voltage>+100mV</voltage>";
string measure = test.Substring(test.IndexOf('>')+1);
measure = measure.Substring(0, measure.IndexOf('<')-1);

// Extract measure unit
string um = measure.Substring(measure.Length - 1);
measure = measure.Substring(0, measure.Length - 1);
// Get value
double val = Double.Parse(measure);
// Convert value according to measure unit
switch (um)
{
    case "G": val *= 1E9; break;
    case "M": val *= 1E6; break;
    case "k": val *= 1E3; break;
    case "m": val /= 1E3; break;
    case "u": val /= 1E6; break;
    case "n": val /= 1E9; break;
    case "p": val /= 1E12; break;
}
```

Comment: Correction: using ToLower() is incorrect, because M=10^6, m=10^-3, P=10^15, p=10^-12

Comment: @AndreyAtapin: oops, you're right, absolutely!! Edited my post to reflect this. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @leppie: well, I don't know how can you write "short" for micro... :)

Comment: Thanks your solution works nice. Also it is just 'u' for micro and 'M' for mega. but in engineering papers you can see it as 'µ'  :P Just For Information. CIAO

Comment: @leppie: thanks... my problem was for micro because it's a greek letter and I didn't remember I could use "u". Thanks!! :)

Answer (score 1):

Hi here is another version of what Marco has written.

```
            string str = "1pV";
            double factor;
            double value;
            switch (str[str.Length-2])
            {
                case 'M': factor = 1E6; break;
                case 'm': factor = 1E-3; break;
                case 'n': factor = 1E-9; break;
                case 'p': factor = 1E-12; break;
                default:
                    factor = 1; break;
            }
            value = double.Parse(str.Substring(0,str.Length-2)) * factor;
```

Assuming that the html text is already available to you. I have tried to do the same thing with one substring, switch case with characters instead of strings(This is a bit faster to comparing strings) and a double.parse. Hope someone comes up with a better version than this.

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats tru, chars should operate faster!

Answer (score 0):

Remove the suffix string `mV` and `nA` using `string.Substring` or `string.Remove()` method and use `double.TryParse()` method to parse string to double.

Answer (score 0):

If your values always have 2 chars on the end you could simple remove these and parse the number.

```
var newstring = fullstring.Substring(0, fullstring.Length - 2);
var number = double.Parse(newstring);
```